# Как правильно начать изучение cgroup2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos

Так получилось, что только через года работы на Linux. Мне понадобился cgroup.
Не много почитав в интернете. Я понял, что информация смешана.
Так как есть cgroup двух версия - 1 и 2. Подскажите ресурсы, а лучше название авторов.
Кто рассматривает на примерах использование данной виртуальной файловой системы для ограничений.